Field and charge distribution in an ellipsoid cavity inside a conductor having a charge at the center
Suppose we have a conductor which have ellipsoid cavity and we put a charge at the center of cavity. We know that every point on the surface of cavity will have same potential. We know the if the cavity was spherical then we would have same field near every point and also same charge distribution. Now in case of ellipsoid radius of curvature is bigger on semi minor axis but is it nearer. Radius of curvature is smaller on semi major axis but there are further.
Can we comment on relative charge density at these point using logic without math. Can we calculate exact value using math?
How can one more forward with this?

This is essentially solving Laplace's equation in ellipsoidal coordinates with appropiate boundary conditions, this may be relevant.
